# Is there a way to put multiple for loops in a def function?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I've written a code using Openpyxl module that searches for multiple instances of a specific word in a column, counts how many times it appears, and then puts the total value in another cell. The code looks like this:

```
word = 0
for i in ws["B"]:
    if i.value == "word":
        word += 1
ws["M2"] = word
```

It works but the issue is that when I need to search for multiple words I have to copy/paste this code for every word changing only **the word itself** and **the cell I want the total value to go to**.

I'm wondering if there is a way to write a function that repeats the loop taking the two variables declared somwhere else.

I've tried looking for a way to create a dictionary that holds two keys X and Y and then assiging each word to X and each column letter to Y (the column number doesn't need to change) but couldn't make it happen and I don't even know if this is the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can define a function taking the word and the column of the output cell as arguments. For example:

```py
def count_word(word: str, out_col: str) -> None:
    cnt = 0
    for i in ws["B"]:
        if i.value == word:
            cnt += 1
    ws[f'{out_col}2'] = cnt
```

Then you can use it with a `dict`:

```py
words = {
    'word1': 'M',
    'word2': 'N',
    'word3': 'O',
}

for word, out_col in words.items():
    count_word(word, out_col)
```

Comment: Hi again, I have one more question because now that I finished my project and put this code to the actual work I realized my mistake. It works but only when the cell contains only the word specified in a dictionary, but what I would like to achieve is the code to search for the word in the entire string in each cell for a specific column. For example, if I'm looking for "cat" and the string is "I have a cat" this won't work. 

Is there a way to modify it so it is more flexible?

Comment: Nevermind, if I did it properly it was just a matter of changing one line of code, from if i.value == word: to if word in i.value: